# CodeIgniter get_where in model by variable post using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

First, let say I want to get a record with primary key 'customer_code' 4, and want to serve them in a form. I can successful made it by a simple function in model like this:

```
public function get_Acustomer()
  {    
    $query = $this->db->get_where('allinone',array('customer_code' => '4'));
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

My question is, How to achieve to make 'customer_code' by variable?

I am using DataTables and by its `fnGetData` I able to get a row record. Here is the jquery:

```
$('#example tbody td').dblclick( function() {
      var TTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

      var tData = oTable.fnGetData( TTr );
      var cc = tData[1]; //tData[1] is my 'customer_code'

      if ( $(TTr).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
        $(TTr).removeClass('row_selected');
      }
      else {
        oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
        $(TTr).addClass('row_selected');          
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>dbcust/update',  
            data: {cc: cc},  
            success: function() {
            }  
        });
      }
```

When user double-click in a row, it send post value of 'cc' to my controller function 'update' and then immediately the controller pass it to model 'get_Acustomer'.

Here is the controller:

```
public function update()
  {  
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->dbcust_model->get_Acustomer();
    $data['title'] = 'Update';
    $data['cust'] = $this->dbcust_model->get_Acustomer();

    //Some validation rules & mesagges
    [skip...skip]

    //finally  
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('cust/template/crud/update-form');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->dbcust_model->edit_dbcust();
      $this->load->view('cust/template/crud/success');
    }  
  }
```

Here is the model:

```
  public function get_Acustomer()
  {   
    $custCode = $this->input->post('cc');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('allinone',array('customer_code' => $custCode));
    return $query->result_array();   
  }
```

Why this simple is just not work? Can Everyone pointing me out?

My goal is, after user double-click a row/selecting a row, and they are clicking on something linking to `http://myhost/dbcust/update`, they will served the form with records of the row.

I Hope my question is quite clear to you all. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to read POST variables inside a model.

Instead get the CC value in the controller. Validate it. Then pass that value to the method in the model.

**Controller**

```
public function update() {  

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $cc = $this->input->post('cc');

    //Validate $cc if everything is OK

    $data['title'] = 'Update';
    $data['cust'] = $this->dbcust_model->get_Acustomer($cc);

    //Some validation rules & mesagges
    [skip...skip]

    //finally  
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('cust/template/crud/update-form');
    } else {
        $this->dbcust_model->edit_dbcust();
        $this->load->view('cust/template/crud/success');
    }  
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_Acustomer($custCode) {   
    $query = $this->db->get_where('allinone',array('customer_code' => $custCode));
    return $query->result_array();   
}
```

Let me know if this works or if there are any other issues in this.

Comment: Also check whether `$custCode` in `get_Acustomer` is getting proper value from the AJAX call or not.

Comment: Dear Vanga, thanks but still not work. bytheway, how to check `$custCode` in `get_Acustomer()` getting proper value?

Comment: Use `error_log` function as described here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php to send a message to server's error log. This will not disturb HTML output in the browser. Or use `var_dump` or `echo` to print the value, but it disturb the HTML output. As you are using AJAX, you will see the output in Browser's Network tab.

Comment: Ah, I can see 'cc' value when user double-clicking in XHR network tab... I also add my update-form.php `<?php var_dump($custCode); ?>` and it give me NULL. Thanks

Comment: As it gives NULL, value of CC is not sent properly to the server. May be we need to check why this is happening.

Comment: As far as I know, the 'cc' first would be sent to myhost/dbcust/update and this is OK (Please see this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/7sjcX.png ). The next thing is the controller would sent 'cc' to model get_Acustomer() and here is the problem occur right? How can I toubleshoot this? thanks

Comment: In the controller check the value of `$cc`, using the methods that we already discussed. If you are not getting proper value then there might be some issue with the configuration.

Comment: Yes it is still get NULL with var_dump($cc), and also error undefined variable cc in update-form.php. But why? As we all see the value of 'cc' was sent to dbcust/update just like I capture for you before. I believe it should be really simple :), isn't it?